# Turning a list of paths into a list of Tasks without forking it

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

Still learning about FP but I feel that I finally started to get my head around monads, specifically on using them. So here is what I have:

```
 /* taken from 
https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/ch08.html#asynchronous-tasks
 */
import fs from 'fs'
import { Task, } from './shared/functional.js';

// readDir :: String -> Task Error (Array String)
const readDir = path => new Task((reject, result) => {
  fs.readdir(path, (err, data) => (err ? reject(err) : result(data)));
});

const readStat = filename => new Task((reject, result) => {
  fs.stat(filename, (err, data) => (err ? reject(err) : result(data)));
});

console.log(readDir('./shared'))
readDir('./shared').fork(console.error,console.log)
```

With the code above I am able to get a array of the contents in that specific directory.
I have two problems:

how I can concat the directory without explicity composing it like below. So I can avoid calling './shared' twice.

```
const dirList = compose(
  chain(map(concat('./shared/')))),
  readDir,
);
```

Second is that, Is it possible to map over the array of string and turn then in an array of tasks without forking the outer Task? I want to get stats for each of the items in the array.
It does not need to be an array of tasks but I want to avoid forking it twice. I would like to call readDir, and with whatever result I might get get stat of the result, which can be a array of stats for ex. instead an array of strings that I would need to turn into Tasks.

Furthest I got was:

```
const dirList = compose(
  map(map(compose(readStat, concat('./shared/')))),
  readDir,
);
```

Any ideas?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: It might be easier if you don't use `compose` that often and use point-ful functions instead and spell out their types explcitly.

Comment: What do you mean by "*avoid calling './shared' twice*"?

Comment: "*Is it possible to map over the array of string and turn then in an array of tasks*" - nothing easier than that: `map(readStat, arrayOfPaths)`. "*without forking the outer Task?*" - what do you mean by that? You shouldn't ever have to `.fork()` a task until the end when you actually *run* the task that comprises the whole program.

Comment: @Berji, I mean before calling stat I need to prefix the path to the string, so I pass './shared' once to read the dir then I have to pass it again for the concat.

yeah I could fork and then with the value have a list tasks that I can then fork again and is exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
// readDir :: String -> Task Error (List String)
const readDir = path => new Task((reject, result) => {
  fs.readdir(path, (err, data) => (err ? reject(err) : result(new List(data))));
});

// readStat :: String -> Task Error Stats
const readStat = filepath => new Task((reject, result) => {
  fs.stat(filepath, (err, data) => (err ? reject(err) : result(data)));
});

// dirList :: String -> Task Error (List Stats)
const dirList = dir => chain(
  traverse(Task.of, compose(readStat, concat(dir))),
  readDir(dir),
);

dirList('./shared/').fork(console.log, console.error);
```

Comment: Ok, this does not work. because we return a function so we can't fork. and traverse needs two arguments. Also if you are trying the result is an array so it is not traversable. So I probably need to deal with that as well.

although this work:

const dirList = path => compose(
  map(map(compose(readStat, concat(path)))),
  compose(readDir, ()=>path),
);

This works for the string arg I will still have an array of Tasks though.

Comment: @RicardoSilva What do you mean by "*we return a function so we can't fork*"? `dirList('./shared/')` does return a `Task`, does it not?

Comment: You are currying it so it will return a function that return a Task.

Comment: @RicardoSilva "*traverse needs two arguments*" - three, actually, I forgot that you need to tell it which applicative to use in JS. Fixed. Then, it will happily traverse the array of strings from the result of the `readDir(dir)` though.

Comment: @RicardoSilva Yes, `dirList` is a function that returns a task. `dirList('./shared/')` then will be said task.

Comment: ok you are are wrapping it with chain, but it does not work for me, so I tried with compose. so I have to do readDir(dir)()

then again. the resulting array does not have a traverse method so it fails right there.

Comment: @RicardoSilva "*you are trying to traverse an array, which does not implement the method.*" - uh, of course arrays should be traversable?! What library are you using exactly, from where do you import the `traverse` that does not work?

Comment: everything is from the book:
https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io
I did not use any library

Comment: @RicardoSilva Ah, [I see](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/appendix_c.html#traverse), that's much more limited than e.g. Ramda's `traverse`. It means that instead of an `Array` you'll want to use a [`List`](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/appendix_b.html#list) of strings as the return value of `readDir`. Change the callback to `(err, data) => (err ? reject(err) : result(new List(data)))`.

Comment: Nice, works like a charm, please make it an answer so I can accept. Thank you very much for the help. one last question (just put it in the answer if it ok).

Which type lib you would recommend? I was going to use folktale but they changed a lot from the last version and I got confused with the new methods for Tasks.

Comment: I haven't used any of them myself so I cannot make a recommendation. However, being based on the fantasy-land spec they're all interoperable with each other, and e.g. Ramda defines useful wrappers or helper functions that work on all algebraic data structures created by the other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi,

Just to show it clearer, the example below work because we get a Maybe which is traversable.

```
const readFirst = path => compose(
  chain(traverse(Task.of, compose(readStat,concat(path)))),
  map(safeHead),
  compose(readDir, ()=>path),
);
const stats = maybe('nope', console.log)
readFirst('./shared/')().fork(console.error, stats)
```

In your comment you are trying to traverse an array, which does not implement the method. I need a way to make the array a traversable, then I guess I can bundle the execution together and return a list of stats when I fork the Task.

Comment: Instead of a `Maybe` you should use a `List` - so replace `safeHead` with `filenames => new List(filenames)`. And I don't see any reason to use `compose` here and return a unit function - just return `chain(traverse(…), map(ns => new List(ns), readDir(path)))`. Or `readDir(path).map(…).chain(traverse(…))` if you find that more readable.